# WPS Office Writer not loading

Tags: 17.10, wps-office

```
android@android-Inspiron-3421:~$ wps
/usr/bin/wps: line 38:  8454 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ${gInstallPath}/office6/${gApp} ${gOptExt} ${gOpt} "$@"
```

WPS writer is not loading. It gives me error above.

Comment: Is it the Writer only? And have you tried to install the latest version?

Comment: yes it is latest. And the problem is for all.

Comment: A shot in the dark: It should have a hidden configuration/profile folder (`.wps` or perhaps the old name `.kingsoft` or...) somewhere in your home folder. Try deleting or renaming it, then reinstall.

Comment: look [here](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme/issues/748). I tried to add the **-style gtk+** parameter and works. I am using debian 9.2.

Answer (score 1):

**-style gtk+** took care of the seg fault for me ! thanks l13s7-ae

I added it to /usr/bin/wpp /usr/bin/wps and /usr/bin/et so it works from menu and file manager.

```
    if [ 1 -eq ${gDaemon} ]; then
        nohup ${gInstallPath}/office6/${gApp} ${gOpt} -style gtk+ > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    else
        ${gInstallPath}/office6/${gApp} ${gOptExt} ${gOpt} -style gtk+ "$@"
    fi
```

Answer (score 1):

GUI solution

The solution is install Qt 4 Settings and change the theme

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig
```

In Ubuntu 16.04 the launcher of this packages is called:

```
qtconfig-qt4
```

this you need to put in a terminal and launch (You can also look for it in the application launcher for your operating system but I can not do a tutorial for all of them since there is: Xubuntu, Ubuntu Studio, Ubuntu Gnome, Kubuntu, e.g.)

open this config dialog and chose GTK+

[image: 01 qtconfig-qt4 en la terminal]

[image: 02 chose GTK+]

[image: 03 Save]

Launch again WPS Office and Working

Viewing in:
WPS Office not working, error
https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=309&t=140892

Answer (score 1):

GTK theme have to be set with environment variable and parameter

```
env GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc ./et -style gtk+
```